# How get partial data or treatment with HttpClient Angular

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I realize a Http get and receive a JSON data. It's cool but I would like return an observable with partial data.
Actual, this my response JSON data:

```
message "Success"
hero    
  id    2
  name  "Spider-Man"
```

I would like return just an hero data in an hero object. Actually this my code but thehero object is false:

```
search(id: number|string): Observable<Hero> {
return this.http.get<Hero>(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/heroes/${id}`, {headers: httpOptions});}
```

I don't know if I have to use an interceptor or realize an other operation.

Thanks per advance.

Comment: it's HttpClient :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.map` operator, that allow modify the flow:

```
...
return this.http.get<Hero>(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/heroes/${id}`, {headers: httpOptions})
  .map( response => response.hero as Hero );
...
```

or with newest rxjs (>5.x)

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
...
return this.http.get<Hero>(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/heroes/${id}`, {headers: httpOptions})
  .pipe( map( response => response.hero as Hero ) );
...
```

Comment: Thanks, but i I don't have the map function and "rxjs/operators/map" is ok. I used HttpClient not HttpModule

Comment: What version of rxjs you are using? You can try `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';` and use this code: `return this.http.get(...).pipe( map(...) )`

Answer (score 1):

You want an interface to determine the actual response that contains your `Hero` (or alternatively use bracket notation when extracting the hero from the response to avoid error) More about that here: [Typechecking the response](https://angular.io/guide/http#type-checking-the-response).

So create an interface if you do not choose to use bracket notation....

```
interface MyResponse {
  message: string;
  hero: Hero;
}
```

Then you specify that you are receiving a response of type `MyResponse` and extract the `hero` from the response using `map` like suggested in other answers:

```
return this.http.get<MyResponse>(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/heroes/${id}` ....}
  .map(res => res.hero as Hero) // here!
```

Comment: Yes, I thought at this solution but... I prefer another solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `map()` operator of the observable to extract a subset of the response:

```
search(id: number|string): Observable<Hero> {
  return this.http.get<any>(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/heroes/${id}`, 
     {headers: httpOptions})
     .map(resp => resp["hero2"] as Hero);
}
```

Comment: map is not available with HttpClient

Comment: Did you try adding it with `import "rxjs/operators/map";` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried again with the import and I don't have the map function